# Git hook not executing gulp without absolute path

Tags: git, bash, gulp, hook, sh

I have a git hook (written in bash) on pre-commit which is supposed to execute the command "gulp".

When I manually run the bash script, it works perfectly.
But when a commit is done, the hook script is called and executed but does not work is the same way as when manually invoked.

The hook script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch log.txt #For testing purposes
pwd > log.txt
gulp >> log.txt

exit 0
```

There is no problem when calling the script directly by hand.

But when called by git on a commit, the log file is well created, pwd is executed and write the path to the log (which is the same path as when I run  it manually). But somehow, if I don't write something like `/usr/bin/gulp` instead of `gulp` the gulp command won't be executed.

I tried to do things such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch log.txt #For testing purposes
pwd > log.txt

path=$(which gulp)
echo $path >> log.txt
$path >> log.txt

exit 0
```

But once again, when not manually launched, the `which` command doesn't seem to return anything.

I must be missing something but I don't know what, any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you don't have the PATH environment variable configured properly for the user that runs the git hooks. Just to be sure, do a `/usr/bin/id >> log.txt` (full path may vary depending on your system) or `echo $USER >> log.txt` to find out which user runs the script, and then check that user's $PATH. PATH may be defined in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment` and user's `~/.bashrc`|`~/.bash_profile`|`~/.profile`|`~/.shrc` depending on both your system and your shell.

`which gulp` won't give you any results here because it also uses $PATH.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try this as soon as possible and come back with the results.

Comment: Okey, I did this, but unfortunately the results when executed by git and by hand are exactly the same for both `$USER` and `/usr/bin/id`.
(The file was removed between each test)
And another thing is that I also tried:
    `path=$(/usr/bin/which gulp)`
    `echo $path >> $logFile`
instead of `which gulp`. But I'm still left with the same results (ie: nothing when executed by git).

Comment: Can you check what's `git` $PATH env variable? E.g. change user to git and do an `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: Okey, you're right ! The git $PATH is missing $HOME/myname/npm-global/bin . But then, should I fuse my $PATH once for all to the git $PATH in order to make it work, or pin point each time what is missing from the git $PATH but that is present in my $PATH ?

Comment: If the portability is not a concern for you, I would just use full paths if I were you, shortcuting them like `gulp=/usr/bin/gulp` and using `$gulp`. On the other hand, I don't see any global issues in fusing `git` user's $PATH if you control the directory you're adding, so no one does anything destructive. But, as you've mentioned `$HOME`, I assume that you want `git` to execute something from your home directory, be sure to check if `git` has permissions to do so, or even better - move your executables to some more conventional place than `$HOME`.

Comment: Well, because the portability kinda matters I went for a "quite" portable solution. There was a script executed at least once before to do some configs on git, it now also registers the full path of gulp for the given configuration and this path is reused later on by the pre-commit hook.
Not the best, but it kinda works. Thanks a lot for your help !